# Alternative to ng-container without the comments?

Tags: angular

When using ng-container it gets rendered as an HTML comment:

```
<div>
    <ng-container>foo</ng-container>
<div>
will produce this kind of output :

<div>
    <!--template bindings={}-->foo
<div>
```

Is there an Angular alternative for ng-container that doesn't produce the comments in the HTML? I ask b/c my app creates legal documents dynamically from a database and each document will be a few dozen pages long and each page has many many components on it that are generated using ng-container with ng-switch. When I look at the HTML source I see 90% of the page are these rendered comments and it also takes up to ten seconds to generate a page dynamically. I haven't counted, but I expect that there are thousands of extraneous comment lines in the page. So I'm hoping to get rid of all the clutter in the HTML and hopefully that can speed up page generation as well. Although my page is generated dynamically, after it's generated the structure doesn't change. For example, I don't need Angular to be able to go back and switch our a text input for with a label. It's static.

Here is a small code snippet to give you an idea of how I'm handling things:

> ```
> <ng-container *ngFor="let ctrl of formTemplate">
>   <ng-container [ngSwitch]="ctrl.component">
>
>    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textinput'">
>       <label *ngIf="!hasAttribute('nolabel', ctrl.attributes)" class="col-sm-2">{{ctrl.displayText}}</label>
>       <ng-container *ngIf="!ctrl.readOnly">
>         <div *ngIf="hasAttribute('full', ctrl.attributes)" class="col-sm-10">
>           <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%" [formControlName]="ctrl.key" />
>         </div>
>       </ng-container>
>       <ng-container *ngIf="ctrl.readOnly">
>           <ng-container *ngIf="hasAttribute('full', ctrl.attributes)">
>               <label class="col-sm-10" style="font-weight: 100">{{protocol[ctrl.objectName][ctrl.fieldName]}}&nbsp;</label>
>             </ng-container>
>         </ng-container>
>     </ng-container>
> ```

Comment: why do you use `ng-container`?

Comment: So that it doesn't leave add unnecessary html to the DOM. Although ng-container leaves comments I assume it makes it faster for Angular to traverse the DOM when necessary without having un-used components everywhere (and in my case we're talking hundred of components that wouldn't be used).

Comment: I dontt know if angular has any type of pre-processor that I could inject my own html into (without reading an actual HTML file)? I was thinking it would be great if I could build a giant string in memory and pass that to Angular as if it was reading the html string itself, but I would be intercepting it and passing it my own html string instead. That would let me build the form dynamically without ng-container and ng-swtich and only the final form would be there. No need to open an actual file. Possible?

Comment: I meant do you use ViewContainerRef or structural directives like ngIf, ngFor with it?

Comment: I updated my original question with a code snippet at the bottom so you can see how I structured it.

Comment: I don't think that comments are somehow related to the performance. Angular operates with pointers to the elements and not with html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an Angular alternative for ng-container that doesn't produce
>   the comments in the HTML

Angular **needs to have some DOM node** in the template to be able to insert elements after it. In the case of `ng-container` it's comments. With the router it's `router-outlet`. Any DOM node can act as an anchor.

Here is the example using native DOM API that shows what Angular does:

```
const comment = document.createComment('ng-container - insert after me');
document.body.appendChild(comment);
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = 'I am inserted after comment';
document.body.insertBefore(span, comment.nextSibling);
```

[Check this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L6XaPZZgo88ECbiMyDbK?p=preview).

If there's no DOM node (no comment in the case of `ng-container`), Angular doesn't have any DOM node to act as an anchor.

Comment: I see what your saying. Basically using JS to update DOM. Makes sense. Hmmm.... Is this possible:
High level overview from a newb's perspective of processing HTML page:
1. Open Html file
2. Load Html code into memory
3. Pass memory blob to Angular engine to do all it's magic.

Now I would like to replace it with:
1. Create Html string manually in memory
2. Pass string blog to Angular engine to do all it's magic. Hence Angular doesn't know that the memory blob was created by me instead of from an HTML file.

Comment: @user441058, no, I'm saying that without comment node Angular can't know where the nodes should be inserted. You need to have some element to act as an anchor.

Comment: On a side note, i pulled up your AngularInDepth site and I see a few blog posts re dynamic components. I'm going to study those posts now.

Comment: @user441058, yeah, go ahead and ask another question specific to dynamic components if you have any

Comment: Yeah, I need to study more. Looks like your site has a lot of info I need. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah - Is my idea possible where instead of Angular reading an html file and then doing it's magic on it, can I create an Html string in memory and then pass that to angular to process? As if it read the html file itself even though I created the string manually? Maybe not since AG has the pre-processor and JS compiler that it uses to optimize pages. But it would be great if there was a way to intercept the router and use a string instead.

Comment: @user441058, start by reading [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) and then you'll have better knowledge to ask specific questions